# Stretching and scaling SVG elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two elements in my `<svg>`:

- `rect` = light brown bg panel
- `path` = dark brown ellipse (circle).

See following example:
[image]

I need to *stretch* the `rect` so that is `100%` of both `width` and `height` of the parent `<div>`, but need to maintain the *scale* of `path` (so the circle's relative `height` is maintained and does not distort to an oval in any context).From the picture supplied you will see that both elements are currently stretching, which is not desirable.

One constraint I have is that the `rect` **must** be an `<svg>` and not a `<div>`.

Here is my code:

```
<svg class="bg container" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%">
  <rect class="rect" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <path class="path" d="M511.99961-16h.0008A399.99959,399.99959,0,0,1,912,383.99959v.00083A399.99959,399.99959,0,0,1,512.00041,784h-.00083A399.99959,399.99959,0,0,1,112,384.00041v-.0008A399.99961,399.99961,0,0,1,511.99961-16Z"/>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" y1="384" x2="1024" y2="384" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f8f7f2"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fcfbf7"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <style>
      .bg.container .rect {
        fill: url(#gradient);
      }
      .bg.container .path {
        fill: #978a60;
        opacity: .08;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance.

**Updated code:**
`path` *converted to* `circle`

```
<svg class="bg container" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%">
  <rect class="rect" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <circle class="cls-2" cx="512" cy="384" r="400">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" y1="384" x2="1024" y2="384" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f8f7f2"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fcfbf7"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <style>
      .bg.container .rect {
        fill: url(#gradient);
      }
      .bg.container .path {
        fill: #978a60;
        opacity: .08;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you just use an SVG `circle` element instead of a `path`? Seems like that'd force it to always be a circle.

Comment: Thank you for this, @ChrisRiebschlager. I will experiment with this and report back. I am using Adobe Illustrator to export my `<svg>`, the following article looks very useful for other people having trouble exporting `<path>`s instead of `<circle>`s: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2345701

Comment: Illustrator is just gonna do whatever it wants. :) But I think your case is simple enough that you could get a circle hand-coded into place.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager: You're right—Illustrator does do exactly what it wants lol. I have updated the code in my initial question to include a `circle`, but the stretching is still occurring.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I'm tracking. So you want something like this fiddle, but the rect will scale width/height independently and the circle will stay a circle and in the center? https://jsfiddle.net/kaf89s93/7/